# Is there a legal way of obtaining all installed apps on an iOS device from within my app?

Tags: objective-c, c, ios

I am making an app that needs to check if certain apps are installed with a given identifier.

Is there a way to do this without private symbols and without a jailbreak?

Thanks.

Comment: Bump now does this. I too was curious as to how this was done.

Comment: Just a note, but jailbreaking and such is NOT illegal.

Comment: @Falmarri it is not illegal by law, but it is illegal when it comes to the Apple's rules.

Comment: S: Apple has absolutely no say on what is legal and what's not. Except through lobbying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Bump](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bump/id305479724?mt=8) developer gives a hint of how they do it [on their blog](http://blog.bu.mp/bump-24-for-ios-now-with-app-sharing) (see comment at the bottom):

> Q: […] How do you check wich
>   applications the end-user have
>   installed? I thought that apple didn't
>   aprove apps that do that..
>
> A: […] There's not a simple way to
>   detect which apps are installed. We
>   use a combination of several methods.
>   If the other app you need to detect
>   has a custom URL registered, you can
>   check to see if that URL exists.
>   Otherwise, you can look for that app's
>   process name running in the
>   background.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for some of the apps, but not all. If the app has a custom URL scheme, you can query the application object to see if it responds:

Here's how to check for AirSharing:

```
NSString *stringURL = @"airsharing://";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

From this page: http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *rootAppPath = @"/Applications";

NSArray *listApp = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:rootAppPath error:nil];

NSLog(@"%@",listApp);
```